# Setting image on tableview header

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I need to set an image on my tableview header.  The problem is that the url for the image is returned by my model asynchronously.  I am called back at some point with the URL.  The same goes for the method `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`.  This also calls back at some point.  The problem is I cannot predict which one comes first.  Therefore, I am not sure how the logic for setting the image should go.  So essentially the problem is the non-deterministic nature of the situation.  I'm sure many have dealt with such a situation before and could help me here.  I'm sure i'm just missing something.

Comment: Are you using AFNetworking to download image?

Comment: No, I'm using SDWebImage to set the imageview but I don't think that is relevant.  I'm getting the URL to set it with from a model class I wrote that calls back to my viewcontroller (the model's delegate) when it is finished.  Therefore, tableview is beginning, or finished its callback series when my viewcontroller gets called back from the model.  I think what I need is a reference to the view that tableview uses for the section header.  That way when the model calls back I can say [<ThatRef>.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:freshURL];